# Separating Clock In and Clock Out data stored within one column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I am having a few issues with finding a solution to separate the date and times in which users have clocked in and clocked out of the current system.

So far the table looks like this:

`10412   Users Name  01/11/2012 07:12
10412   Users Name  01/11/2012 17.15
10412   Users Name  04/11/2012 07:47
10412   Users Name  04/11/2012 17:13`

Using SQL Server and programming within a C# environment, the main function I need is to define the two date and times into their own columns without having to redo the whole database.

Any help would be much appreciated,

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have your considered [`VIEW`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214068%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)?

Comment: How do you know which are clock ins and clock outs if a user misses to do it one day or has a doctor's appointment and clocks in/out more than once per day?

Comment: Please extend on this answer I'm not too experienced with SQL and have limited knowledge...

Comment: I have other tables in place on the server that defines whether or not the user clocked in on that day, that form of query is easier than this one as its something I am experienced with.

Comment: I basically need to separate the current time-stamp into two columns, one defining the 'Clock-in' and the other 'Clock-out'.

Comment: Just having issues in finding a solution to extract the two different events and place them into their individual columns for report viewing.

Comment: Is this SQL Server 2008 or 2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter("SET ROWCOUNT 10 SELECT USERINFO.USERID [User ID], USERINFO.NAME [Name], USERINFO.DEFAULTDEPTID [Dept.],CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME,103) [Date], MIN(CONVERT (VARCHAR(5),CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME,108)) [Clock In], MAX(CONVERT (VARCHAR(5),CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME,108)) [Clock Out] FROM USERINFO ,CHECKINOUT where USERINFO.USERID = CHECKINOUT.USERID GROUP BY USERINFO.USERID, USERINFO.NAME, USERINFO.DEFAULTDEPTID, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME, 103)", con);
        sda1.Fill(dta);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dta;
```

With a lot of hard work and code filtering I was able to create the perfect 'Clock In/ Out' function for my program, thanks for all your help people...

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not defining the problem very clearly, I'll go for the easiest case that covers your sample;

If there can be only one single checkin/checkout per day, a simple `GROUP BY` will solve the problem; just take the min time per day as checkin time and max time as checkout.

```
SELECT user_id, user_name, MIN(clock_time) clock_in, MAX(clock_time) clock_out
FROM myTable
GROUP BY user_id, user_name, DATEPART(yy, clock_time), DATEPART(y,  clock_time)
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb12f/1).

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is to enumerate the columns and then aggregate by pairs.  This uses the `row_number()` function:

```
select userId, userName, min(clocktime) as clock_in, max(clocktime) as clockout     
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by userId, userName order by clocktime) as seqnum
      table t
     ) t
group by userid, userName, (seqnum - 1) / 2;
```

Note that SQL Server does integer arithmetic, so 3/2 is 1 and not 1.5.